# How to set text of textbox in windows form by parallel-processing?

Tags: c#, winforms, parallel-processing

I use parallel processing for done number methods

```
        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AppendTextBox(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + @"   <<<  Start  >>>");
            _isStop = false;
            Parallel.Invoke(
                    () => GetCheapestFlightGeshm(),
                    () => GetCheapestFlightAbadan(),
                    () => GetCheapestFlightKermanshah(),
                    () => GetCheapestFlightBandarAbbas()
                    );
            AppendTextBox(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + @"   <<<  End  >>>");
        }
------------------------------------------------------
public void AppendTextBox(string value)
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.Invoke(new Action<string>(AppendTextBox), new object[] { value });

            }
            txtResult.Text += value + "\n";
        }
```

`AppendTextBox` method called in `GetCheapestFlightGeshm,GetCheapestFlightAbadan,GetCheapestFlightKermanshah,GetCheapestFlightBandarAbbas` methods!

When run project first message display in textbox only.I debug project and I have not any  exception.
How to solve this?

Comment: I couldn't figure out your problem. Please provide some additional details.

Comment: Always AppendTextBox method run with out exception but text of textbox assigned in first call only

Comment: My general goal  is run number method simultaneously.I should  display result of methods performed

Comment: Is Multiline property set to true for txtResult? Exceptions could be swallowed, so look at output window. Thay should show up there.

Comment: You should add `return;` after `this.Invoke(...);`, otherwise it will execute `txtResult.Text += value + "\n";` in the background thread as well. Alternatively you can also wrap it in an `else`: `else { txtResult.Text += value + "\n"; }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting the control text like this:  `txtResult.Text += value + "\n";`

change it to :  `txtResult.Invoke((Action)(() => txtResult.Text += value + "\n" ));`

Since you are running your function asynchronously you can't change the UI by simply setting the `Text` proprty of the control. You need to call the `Invoke` method.

Comment: But he's already calling `Invoke()` in his `if(this.InvokeRequired)` statement! All he needs to do is wrap the `txtResult.Text += ...` line in an `else`-statement and his code will work. Your suggested change will force it to invoke whether it is necessary or not, which will be a waste of time and system resources if it isn't. And since he's already invoking in his `if`-statement, it'll be done _**twice**_ which is even more wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

The `Control.Invoke()` call doesn't exit the method, meaning when you call `AppendTextBox()` from a background thread it will also reach the:

```
txtResult.Text += value + "\n";
```

...line from the thread ***without*** invoking. Thus (trying) to execute it twice, which doesn't work the second time since you're trying to access `txtResult` from a background thread.

```
if (this.InvokeRequired)
{
    this.Invoke(new Action<string>(AppendTextBox), new object[] { value });
    //Your problem is here.
    //Code execution will continue on the next line after the invoke is complete.
}
txtResult.Text += value + "\n";
```

Either add a `return;` call inside the `if`-statement:

```
if (this.InvokeRequired)
{
    this.Invoke(new Action<string>(AppendTextBox), new object[] { value });
    return; //Stop execution of this method.
}
txtResult.Text += value + "\n";
```

...or wrap the last line in an `else`-statement:

```
if (this.InvokeRequired)
{
    this.Invoke(new Action<string>(AppendTextBox), new object[] { value });
}
else
{
    txtResult.Text += value + "\n";
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

It seems your invoke isn't working properly, try this:

```
if (this.InvokeRequired)
{
    this.Invoke((Action)(() => AppendTextBox(value)));
}
else
{
    txtResult.Text += value + "\n";
}
```

Comment: Your code do not work currently but @ShaiAharoni code work

Comment: @programmer138200 : Edited my answer. While his answer might work, forcing it to invoke is bad practice.